# Authorization Code PKCE - can backend request token using the code?

Tags: oauth, openid-connect

In Authorization Code flow.
Frontend can send the auth-code to backend, and backend may using the code request token from Auth Server.

Now imagine we have SPA frontend, and PKCE used.
Is it still possible that frontend sends the code to backend, and backend requests token using its client credentials?
I mean, the backend does not know the proof key secret generated by the frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not mix and match PKCE with a client secret, but a common solution is to proxy the Authorization Code Grant message via a back end:

- Send the PKCE verifier from browser to the back end
- Then send the verifier to the Authorization Server

This can be a mechanism for keeping access tokens, or refresh tokens, or both, out of the browser. As an example, my [Sample SPA](https://authguidance.com/2020/07/21/spa-reverse-proxy-based-token-renewal/) works like this.

Comment: Thank you! One more question. Is it allowed in OAuth that the backend gets a token (created by frontend using pkce) without pkce but with its own client credentials?

I mean, frontend in this scenario is using pkce, and backend - client credentials.

Comment: That won't work - you either use Authorization Code Flow (with a client secret) or Authorization Code Flow (PKCE). The Authorization Server validates the second step (Authorization Code Grant) of each flow depending on the parameters of the first step (Authorization Redirect).